# Props become undefined when trying to render a component inside another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rendering

I'm trying to render the `BookList` component inside the `ProfilePage` component, but I've run into a problem I can't seem to fix on my own, mainly because I'm not at all sure what the cause is.
Here is the `ProfilePage` Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUser, deleteBook } from '../actions/actions';
import { addFlashMessage } from '../actions/flashMessages';
import BookList from './BookList';

class ProfilePage extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount = () => {
        // Get user data by username
        this.props.getUser(this.props.match.params.username)
            .catch(err => {
                this.props.addFlashMessage({
                    type: 'error',
                    text: err.response.data.error,
                })
            });
    };

    render() {
        const { picture, name, email, books } = this.props.profileUser;
        console.log(picture, name, email, books);
        const whenOwner = (
            <div className="extra">
                <div className="ui right floated primary button">
                    Edit
                    <i className="right edit icon"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
        return (
            <div className="ui items">
                <div className="item">
                    <div className="ui small image">
                        <img src={picture || 'https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png'} alt="Profile picture"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <div className="header">
                            {name}
                        </div>
                        <div className="description">
                            <p>{email}</p>
                        </div>
                        {this.props.currentUser && whenOwner}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/*<BookList books={books} deleteBook={this.props.deleteBook}/>*/}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    if(state.auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return {
            currentUser: state.auth,
            profileUser: state.user
        }
    } else {
        console.log(state);
        return {
            profileUser: state.user
        }
    }
}

React.propTypes = {
    profileUser: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    currentUser: React.PropTypes.object,
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUser, addFlashMessage, deleteBook })(ProfilePage);
```

When `BookList` is commented out the page renders just fine. The relevant props for `BookList` are also all there. But as soon as I uncomment `BookList` I get an error that `books` (`this.props.profileUser.books`) is undefined.
This is the exact error React throws:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
BookList
C:\Users\erody\WebstormProjects\book_trading_club\src\components\BookList.js:16
```

I doubt that there is a problem with the `BookList` component itself, because I'm using it somewhere else and it's working fine there. But here it is anyways:

```
import React from 'react';
import BookCard from './BookCard';

const BookList = ({books, deleteBook}) => {

    console.log(books);

    const emptyMessage = (
        <p>
            There are no books.
        </p>
    );

    const bookList = (
        <div className="ui five cards">
            { books.map(book => <BookCard deleteBook={deleteBook} book={book} key={book._id}/>)}
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <div>
            {books.length ? bookList : emptyMessage}
        </div>
    )
};

BookList.propTypes = {
    books: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    deleteBook: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default BookList;
```

When looking through Redux devtools everything seems fine. The action is dispatched and the state is updated correctly.
If it would help if I added the action and the relevant reducer I can add those as well, I just didn't want to make this post too long.

Comment: Seems to me like `this.props.profileUser.books` is not an array. Can you show your console.log output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to map the books object when the bookList object is declared. And you try to do this without verifying if books is defined or not.

So, the workflow of this:

1. Declare the bookList -> try-ing to map books object
2. return -> verify if books.length > 0 -> render something

The solution to your code can be this:

```
const bookList = books && books.length ? (
    <div className="ui five cards">
        { books.map(book => <BookCard deleteBook={deleteBook} book={book} key={book._id}/>)}
    </div>
) : emptyMessage;

return (
    <div>
        {bookList}
    </div>
);
```